# Windows batch file to get C:\ drive total space and free space available

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, size, volume

I need a bat file to get C:\ drive total space and free space available in GB (giga bytes) in a Windows system and create a text file with the details.

Note: i dont want to use any external utilities.

Comment: I don't see a programming question (any question for that matter). Even if you rephrase into a proper programming question, there is no solution using native batch because native batch cannot perform math on the large numbers that you will see in today's disk drives. Pure native batch could provide free bytes, but not free GB.

Comment: By "external utilities," do you mean that you only want to use things that ship with Windows (version?, 7?), like fsutil, wmic, etc.? What about PowerShell or VBScript? They ship with Windows.

Answer (score 4):

cut 9 digits of the size by bytes to get the size in GB:

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "volume=C:"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %volume%') DO (
    SET "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    SET "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    SET "diskavail=%%j"
)
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%i IN ("%disktotal% %diskavail%") DO SET "disktotal=%%i"& SET "diskavail=%%j"
(ECHO(Information for volume %volume%
ECHO(total  %disktotal:~0,-9% GB
ECHO(avail. %diskavail:~0,-9% GB)>size.txt
TYPE size.txt
```

cmd can calculate only with numbers up to `2^31-1`   (2,147,483,647 ~ 2.000001 Gigabytes)

Comment: On my Win7 machine there is no additional space or other character after the number, so length should be -9, not -10. Also, this only approximates GB. I think you know that, but your answer as worded might be misleading to some.

Comment: The output depends on local/regional settings (like robocopy), I will change this to a more 'american style' for now. The GB values are not mathematical correct and may vary +/- 1GB, more important for small volumes.

Comment: You could add one more FOR /F loop with delims=space to strip out leading and trailing spaces from value. Then you your answer isn't affected by regional settings.

Comment: I don't know why I'm assuming the trailing character is a space :/ ?

Comment: I have a leading space (between `:`  and the number of bytes).

Comment: If there is never an extra trailing character, regardless of locale, then the length should definitely be -9. Your edited code is definitely wrong. It should be `%var:~0,-9%` with the extra FOR /F, or `%var:~1,-9%` without. I assume the leading space is constant across locales.

Comment: @dbenham yes, you are right and I'm a bit confused, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete solution by any means, but someone might find this helpful:

```
dir | find "bytes"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not at all what you want since it uses PowerShell, but "external utilities" is a bit nebulous and leaves me some wiggle room. Plus, it's essentially a one-liner.

```
SETLOCAL

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%f IN (`PowerShell -NoProfile -EncodedCommand "CgBnAHcAbQBpACAAVwBpAG4AMwAyAF8ATABvAGcAaQBjAGEAbABEAGkAcwBrACAALQBGAGkAbAB0AGUAcgAgACIAQwBhAHAAdABpAG8AbgA9ACcAQwA6ACcAIgB8ACUAewAkAGcAPQAxADAANwAzADcANAAxADgAMgA0ADsAWwBpAG4AdABdACQAZgA9ACgAJABfAC4ARgByAGUAZQBTAHAAYQBjAGUALwAkAGcAKQA7AFsAaQBuAHQAXQAkAHQAPQAoACQAXwAuAFMAaQB6AGUALwAkAGcAKQA7AFcAcgBpAHQAZQAtAEgAbwBzAHQAIAAoACQAdAAtACQAZgApACwAJABmAH0ACgA="`) DO ((SET U=%%f)&(SET F=%%g))

@ECHO Used: %U%
@ECHO Free: %F%
```

Since batch/CMD is bad at nearly everything, I decided to use PowerShell, which is meant for such stuff and has quick and easy access to WMI.

Here's the PowerShell code:

```
Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE Caption='C:'" `
  | % { 
      $f = [System.Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1024/1024/1024,1);
      $t = [System.Math]::Round($_.Size/1024/1024/1024,1);
      Write-Host ('' + ($t-$f) + ',' + $f);
  }
```

This spits out the two values separated by a comma. Now, if only we could do this in a FOR loop!

PowerShell has the nice ability to accept a Base64-encoded command (to eliminate the need for escaping and making the code hard to read), so all we need to do is shrink this command as much as possible (to reduce the size of the encoded string—strictly a nicety, not absolutely necessary). I also reduced the sizes to integers, which rounded them. It's at least closer than discarding the lower-order decimal digits.

Shrinking the encoded command and encoding it in PowerShell looks like this:

```
$code = {
gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "Caption='C:'"|%{$g=1073741824;[int]$f=($_.FreeSpace/$g);[int]$t=($_.Size/$g);Write-Host ($t-$f),$f}
}
$enc = [convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code))
Write-Host $enc
```

(See PowerShell /? for more details.)

I would expect this to run on any Win7 or Win8 machine in existence. The PoSH code doesn't rely on any advanced features (except maybe the EncodedCommand bit), so if PoSH is installed on the XP or Vista machine, there's a good chance of it working. I can't speak about the history of MS pushing PoSH via Windows Update, but I think there's a good chance that this will work ubiquitously.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in batch:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%S in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, FreeSpace ^| findstr "^C:"') do set space=%%S
echo %space%
```