# Calculate used disk space in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255925/windows-batch-file-to-get-c-drive-total-space-and-free-space-available) question for getting disk size information.
I am quite new to batch programming so please be patient here.

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "volume=C:"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %volume%') DO (
    SET "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    SET "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    SET "diskavail=%%j"
)
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%i IN ("%disktotal% %diskavail%") DO SET "disktotal=%%i"& SET "diskavail=%%j"
(ECHO(Information for volume %volume%
ECHO(TOTAL SIZE  ---------- %disktotal:~0,-9% GB
ECHO(AVAILABLE SIZE ------- %diskavail:~0,-9% GB)
pause
```

The result is this:

```
Information for volume C:
TOTAL SIZE  ---------- 240 GB
AVAILABLE SIZE ------- 135 GB
```

How can I now calculate the used disk space by subtracting the available size from the total size? I know I have to use the `SET` command and `/A` but I do not know how to implement it right.

Comment: Use `SET /A` to subtract one variable from the other.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand completely. How do you do this? Perhaps you can post an answer suggestion?

Comment: Also if anybody can give me a hint as to why I get negative rating on the question. I have done research, I have managed to do some parts of the problem and I have explained properly.

Comment: Within the context of your question (getting _used_ disk space), it doesn't appear that you've done any research. You didn't even Google how to use the `set` command, which would tell you exactly how to use the `/a` flag.

Comment: Thanks for lett ting me know. I have done quite some research actually, and I have found some info, but I am not sure how to use that information.

Comment: It took some tinkering and thinking to figure out how you're bumping the values along in the variables like a shift register.  Also I was confused that %j is not declared but automatically defined as the next value FOR finds after the delimiter.  What is this called?

Comment: Just a quick note the 1 answer is slightly incorrect: ***Your original for no apparent reason makes a meal of assigning the values of disktotal and diskavail - it's redundant because they've already been assigned by the previous for*** If you do NOT put in the second "For" statement the output file will incorrectly displayed e.g.
The ops question output info is to 3 digits whereas without the second "For" statement the output is four digits long, a bit picky of me I know but a decimal place would need inserting in the output if the second For statement is omitted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%i IN ("%disktotal% %diskavail%") DO SET "disktotal=%%i"& SET "diskavail=%%j"
(ECHO(Information for volume %volume%
ECHO(TOTAL SIZE  ---------- %disktotal:~0,-9% GB
ECHO(AVAILABLE SIZE ------- %diskavail:~0,-9% GB)
```

with this:

```
SET /a diskused=%disktotal:~0,-9% - %diskavail:~0,-9%
ECHO(Information for volume %volume%
ECHO(TOTAL SIZE  ---------- %disktotal:~0,-9% GB
ECHO(AVAILABLE SIZE ------- %diskavail:~0,-9% GB
ECHO(USED SIZE ------------ %diskused% GB
```

Your original for no apparent reason makes a meal of assigning the values of `disktotal` and `diskavail` - it's redundant because they've already been assigned by the previous `for`.

The calculation is made using `set /a`, subtracting the available from the total, in GB.

Comment: This may be a little off topic but do you know why the size information is different from what windows explorer shows?

Comment: Traditionally in computing, 1024 bytes = 1Kb; 1024*1024=1Mb, 1024*1024*1024=1Gb. These are sometimes termed "Kilibyte, Megibyte, Gigibyte". Your calculation simply divides by 10^9 and uses the common interpretation. Thus there's a 2+% difference. Marketeers commonly use the common rather than the industry or jargon term because it results in a higher number, making the ram/drive size/whatever seem bigger to the unaware. Batch maths is limited to integers < 2^31, so a far more complicated arrangement would have to be made to make the numbers accurate in jargon terms.

Answer (score 0):

bc = [Batch calculator](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm)
mailsend = [MailSend](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mailsend.mirror)

```
@ECHO off
REM =========Funzione da Windows 2003 SP2 in poi===========

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

%~d0
cd %~p0

FOR %%v IN (c: d: e: f: g: h: i: j: k: l: m: n: o: p: q: r: s: t: u: v: w: x: y: z:) DO (

IF EXIST %%v\ (

SET liberi=0
SET totali=0
SET k=1
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:"  %%a IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %%v') DO (
    IF !k!==1 SET liberi=%%a
    IF !k!==2 SET totali=%%a
    SET /A k = !k! + 1
)


echo 100 * !liberi! / !totali!|bc>"%temp%\vai.txt"
set /p percentuale=<"%temp%\vai.txt"

IF !percentuale! LEQ 3 (mailsend.exe -t recipient@email.com -f sender@gmail.com -ssl -port 465 -auth -smtp smtp.gmail.com -user sender@gmail.com -pass YourGmailPassword -sub "[%computername%]Mancanza di spazio libero"  -M "Il Volume %%v ha spazio libero inferiore al 3%%")

)

)

DEL "%temp%\vai.txt"
```